# What is wrong with this simple type definition? (Expecting one more argument to...)

Tags: haskell

basic.hs:

```
areaCircle :: Floating -> Floating
areaCircle r = pi * r * r
```

Command:

```
*Main> :l basic.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Sheet1.hs, interpreted )

Sheet1.hs:2:15:
    Expecting one more argument to `Floating'
    In the type signature for `areaCircle':
      areaCircle :: Floating -> Floating
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I see that `areaCircle :: Floating a => a -> a` loads as expected. Why is the above version not acceptable?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because your version does not actually supply a type. `Floating` is a type class. If you want to allow *any* Floating, then `Floating a => a -> a` is correct. Otherwise you can try either `Float -> Float` or `Double -> Double`.

Just to flesh it out a bit more: `Floating a => a -> a` says not only that your function accepts any `Floating` type, but that it returns the same type it is passed. This must be true even if you narrow the type. For example, you would not be able to use `Float -> Double` without doing some additional conversions

Answer (score 17):

`Floating` isn't a type, it's a type *class*. You can't use a type class as a type like you are. When you say `Floating` in Haskell you're asserting that the following type is an instance of the class. So, for example, you could write the code as

```
areaCircle :: Floating a => a -> a
areaCircle r = pi * r * r
```

which you can read informally as: for any type `a`, if `a` is an instance of the class `Floating` then `areaCircle` can be used as a function from `a` to `a`.

You can think of `Floating` as a bit like an adjective. It describes types. But you're trying to use it like a noun, ie. as a type itself.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class